# How to correctly expose Android SDK to Jenkins user?

Tags: android, macos, jenkins, osx-yosemite

Few days ago I installed Jenkins on my Mac. As you probably already know installer creates dedicated jenkins user. My question is: how to correctly expose Android SDK to jenkins user? Or how to share Android SDK between OSX users?

Some people advise to keep it in `/opt/`. What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `/opt/` is a pretty good place for it, yes. It's probably the most common place to store the SDK. In the end, it doesn't matter where you put it as long as it fits your needs. Alternatively you could also install a second instance of the SDK just for the Jenkins user but i see no reason to do so.